# Necessidade real de reputação para comentar

Tags: suporte, comentários

Muitas vezes me deparo com uma questão, ao analisar perguntas de alguns usuários que estão mal estruturadas ou mal redigidas.

> Será realmente necessário um usuário ter a reputação acima de 50 para
>   comentar em perguntas ou respostas?

Visto que a possibilidade de perguntar e responder existe para qualquer usuário, não vejo sentido em limitar a possibilidade de comentar, na minha concepção isso só limita aqueles que estão tentando entender a pergunta ou a necessidade de quem perguntou.

Não consigo imaginar o impacto negativo que isso poderia causar na comunidade caso fosse liberado.

Algum usuário por favor poderia me ajudar a entender:

> Qual seria o impacto negativo da liberação dos comentários para todos
>   usuários?

Comment: Claro, 50 pontos vc consegue em um ou 2 dias se estiver realmente interessado em participar, eu mesmo em 1 dia consegui 200, pq respondi algumas perguntas sem resposta que foram úteis a comunidade, ou seja mostrei o **esforço minimo** com boas, ou seja eu mostrei que vim para ajudar e ganhei o privilégio de comentar, se liberar isto para qualquer um que chega vai poluir a comunidade, talvez você não saiba mas existem muitos SPAMMERs na internet... Tenha em mente que o sistema é uma máquina e não um humano capaz de detectar suas intenções pelas suas palavras, gestos e olhares. Seja bem vindo!